# Dockerfile COPY and keep folder structure

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I'm trying to create a Dockerfile that copies all `package.json` files into the image but keeps the folder structure.

This what I have now:

```
FROM node:15.9.0-alpine as base
WORKDIR /app/
COPY ./**/package.json ./
CMD ls -laR /app
```

Running with: `sudo docker run --rm -it $(sudo docker build -q .)`
But it only copies 1 `package.json` and puts it in the base dir (`/app`)

Here is the directory I'm testings on:

```
├── Dockerfile
├── t1
│   └── package.json
└── t2
    └── ttt
        ├── b.txt
        └── package.json
```

And i would like it to look like this inside the container:

```
├── Dockerfile
├── t1
│   └── package.json
└── t2
    └── ttt
        └── package.json
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After a lot of searching around, I managed to find a solution that works for me

I ended up creating a tar of all the package.json files

```bash
tar --exclude node_modules -cf package.json.tar  */package.json
```

And using the docker add command to unpack that tar inside the image

```
ADD package.json.tar .
```

The add command will detect that the input is a tar file, and will extract it inside the image.

The down side of using this approach is you have to run the tar command sometime before you build the image.

Answer (score 4):

The Dockerfile [`COPY`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy) directive is documented as using the [Go `filepath.Match` function](https://pkg.go.dev/path/filepath#Match) for glob expansion.  That only supports the basic glob characters `*`, `?`, `[a-z]`, but not extensions like `**` that some shells support.

Since `COPY` only takes a filename glob as input and it likes to flatten the file structure, I don't think there's a way to do the sort of selective copy you're describing in a single command.

Instead you need to list out the individual files you want to copy.  `COPY` will create directories as needed, but that means you need to repeat paths on both sides of `COPY`.

```sh
COPY t1/package*.json t1/
COPY t2/ttt/package*.json t2/ttt/
```

I can imagine some hacky approaches using multi-stage builds; have an initial stage that copies in the entire source tree but then deletes all of the files except `package*.json`, then copies that into the actual build stage.  I'd contemplate splitting my repository into smaller modules with separate Dockerfiles per module first.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, If i copy all the source and delete, i think i will lose the `npm install` cache. In my repo im using lerna with lerna-dockerize do create a single dockerfile with build stages for every package. but i want to install all the dependencies in the first stage so i wont need to reDownload them in each microservice

Comment: This is where a separate build stage potentially comes in: it's possible that if you `COPY --from=an-earlier-stage` and the specific files that get copied are unmodified, it won't invalidate the cache.  I haven't tried that approach, though.